# ifort -coarray=shared produces incorrect exit status

Tags: cmake, fortran, intel-fortran

If I compile and run

```
! main.f90
  print*, 1/0
end program
```

with `ifort` then I get a division by zero error with an exit status of 2 (echo $?), as expected. However, If I compile using `ifort -coarray=shared` then I still get the error but now the exit status is 0. The problem is that CTest is unable to catch the error. This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(testing Fortran)
enable_testing()
add_executable(main EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL main.f90)
add_test(main main)
add_custom_target(check COMMAND ctest DEPENDS main)
```

If I run `make check` then the output is

```
100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1
```

even though the test actually failed. If I remove `-coarray=shared` or use gfortran then I get the correct output

```
0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1
```

How can I make CTest report that the test failed? Am I doing something wrong or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: I don't see any question, not even a question mark in your post. If you think it is a bug, there are official bug reporting forums and support systems on the Intel's website.

Comment: I added a question, to be clear. I'm fairly new to CMake so I should be careful about reporting the above as a compiler bug without being sure.

Comment: If you run your `main` executable directly from a shell, what error code you get?

Comment: From the shell I get an error starting with "forrtl: severe (71): integer divide by zero ...". However, the exit code is still 0.

Comment: In CMake/CTest, you can set properties on tests to check things besides the return status of the test, like fail/pass if a certain regexp is found in the output. If you post the output of `crest —verbose` for your broken example we could help you come up with the proper modifications to your CMakeLists.txt. As Steve noted, there’s not really a standardized return status in Fortran, especially for SPMD programs.

Comment: It seems that in parallel all error messages contain the phrase "BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES". I can set the FAIL_REGULAR_EXPRESSION value to "BAD TERMINATION" which pretty much solves the main problem. However, there are some custom printed messages in which case the test should also fail. How can I set the test properties so that the test fails if either message A or B is printed?

Comment: Found it. If the test should fail with either message A or B the regexp should be "(A|B)".

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing with ifort 14.0.1 with the example code

```
program test
  implicit none
  print *, 1/0
end program
```

I can't quite replicate your initial return value of `3`.  In my testing the result of `echo $?` is `71`, which correlates to the message thrown from the runtime error (note: gfortran won't even compile the example):

```
forrtl: severe (71): integer divide by zero
```

I am however replicating your return code of `0` from the coarray version.  What is happening here is a bit more complicated, as ifort implements coarrays through MPI calls and for `-coarray=shared` basically wraps your program in a wrapper so you do not have to call `mpirun`, `mpiexec` or have to run intel's `mpd` to handle MPI communications.  It is clear that the coarray images (MPI ranks) are all returning with error code 3:

```
application called MPI_Abort(comm=0x84000000, 3) - process 4
```

and

```
exit status of rank 1: return code 3
```

is emitted by each MPI rank, but the executable itself always returns with exit code 0.  Whether this is the intended behavior or a bug is not clear to me, but it seems likely that the wrapper code to launch the MPI processes doesn't look at the MPI return codes from each rank.  As pointed out in the comments, how would we expect different return values from different mpi ranks to be handled?  It doesn't seem you are doing anything wrong.

Contrast this with a normal MPI example:

```
program mpitest
  use mpi
  implicit none
  integer :: rank, msize, merror, mstatus(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
  call MPI_INIT(merror)
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, msize, merror)
  call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, merror)
  print *, 1/0
  call MPI_FINALIZE(merror)
end program
```

compiled with

```
mpiifort -o testmpi testmpi.f90
```

and run as (with `mpd` running):

```
mpirun -np 4 ./testmpi
```

This produced a severe runtime error 71 for integer divide by zero for each rank as before, but the error code is propagated back to the shell:

```
$ echo $?
71
```

Comment: I also had the feeling that while each image returns the correct exit code, the code somehow doesn't propagate through the wrapper executable. I'll bring this issue to the Intel forums.

Comment: What would you expect to be returned to the shell if image 1 exited with status 3 and image 2 with status 4? I'll comment that casey's MPI example is not comparable, as one can ask MPI for an error status. Fortran doesn't have the concept of an exit status that propagates or even that is returned. (You can ask for a status of a particular operation.)

Now, the Fortran standard does "recommend" that with ERROR STOP that the value be supplied as the process exit status, and I see we don't do that. Maybe if one image ends in an abnormal way we can propagate its status as a feature.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, it now makes sense to me. The problem is that I'm currently writing tests for a software package and with coarrays the tests always pass (unless they fail to compile). Ideally the exit code should be non-zero if there is a problem with any of the images (in my actual program the flow of control encounters an error stop). If I can't think of anything else, I guess I'll just run the tests in serial.

Comment: I've asked the developers to see if ERROR STOP, at least, can propagate the stop-code. The standard "recommends" that this happen.